# Does the reaction from the Tomb of Levistus warlock invocation interrupt (and halt) ongoing movement?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, movement, eldritch-invocations

I've been wondering about the following scenario:
Our party is moving through a dungeon and comes upon a wall of fire.
To proceed, we need to pass through. Dispelling does not work and
we have no *wish* spell or *antimagic field*.

Say my Warlock makes a running jump through the wall, triggering Tomb of Levistus to negate much (if not all) of the damage. The invocation itself says: 'your speed is reduced to 0'.
Does that negate the ongoing momentum of the jump, causing the warlock to come to a halt?
Or can the momentum from the jump carry him completely through the wall of fire?

Comment: Related: "[What happens when you run out of movement while jumping?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57165)"

Comment: Do any of your players know what the cantrip "resistance" does?  It's a prefect fit for situations like this ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Yes. Jumping uses your available movement.

The rules for long jumps state:

> Either way, each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement.

Tomb of Levistus says:

> your speed is reduced to 0

When your speed is reduced to 0 by Tomb of Levistus, you no longer have movement available to use on your jump, *and your speed is 0 on your next turn*, so your jump ends and you should fall to the ground wherever you were when you activated Tomb of Levistus.

This is how the rules as written handles this scenario, but a generous DM may choose to reward creative problem solving here and let you get away with it. As a DM, I tend to reward creative problem solving like this one time, and then have a conversation with the player after the session, explaining that I gave it to them this time, but moving forward, it would not work this way.

Comment: Just ask the Barbarian to hurl you across the room :D

Comment: @BlueMoon93 "Don't tell the Elf."